# How to validate this context? In the validate method()?

Tags: laravel

**Context:** When a user creates a new conference he needs to select a start and an end date for the conference and the user needs to enter an end date after the start date, that is, the end date needs to be after the start date.

To deal with this logic properly, do you know if we can use the laravel validate method in the store method or is not a good approach or not possible do with this method? If it is not adequate to do this in the validate method do you know how to properly do that?

**ConferenceController store method:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'conference_name' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'conference_startDate' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y',
            'conference_endDate' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y',
        ]);
        $conference = Conference::create([
            'nome' => $request->conference_name,
            'startDate' => Carbon::parse($request->conference_startDate),
            'endDate' => Carbon::parse($request->conference_endDate),
        ]);
    }
```

**Html fields:**

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="conference_startDate">Stard Date</label>
        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input type='text' onkeydown="event.preventDefault()"
                   name="conference_startDate" value="{{ old('conference_startDate') }}"
                   class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY" />
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="conference_endDate">End Date</label>
        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input type='text' class="form-control"
                   value="{{ old('conference_endDate') }}" name="conference_endDate" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-after), you could use the `after` rule:

> ## after:date
>
> The field under validation must be a value after a given date. The
>   dates will be passed into the  strtotime PHP function:
>
> `'start_date' => 'required|date|after:tomorrow'`
>
> Instead of passing a
>   date string to be evaluated by strtotime, you may specify another
>   field to compare against the date:
>
> `'finish_date' => 'required|date|after:start_date'`

So in your code:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'conference_name' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'conference_startDate' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y',
            'conference_endDate' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y|after:conference_startDate',
        ]);
```

Also, check [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-date-validation?page=1) similar question.

---

### Update

To check for a date after of equal another date, as stated in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-after-or-equal), you should use:

> ## after_or_equal:date
>
> The field under validation must be a value after
>   or equal to the given date. For more information, see the after rule.

Comment: To that case you should use `after_or_equal` validation rule. Check de [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-after-or-equal). As a side note, I encorage you -in a good way- to look in the documentation for solutions before posting it here. Laravel documentation is really well written an easier to navigate than other frameworks. then if you can't find your solution this is the place. Good luck in your project.